# Can't get value using json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
     <!-- QUERY -->
                    $insertstatement = 'SELECT count(*) co FROM `tbl_user` WHERE username="'.$username.'" AND password="'.$password.'"';
                    
                    $query123 = mysql_query($insertstatement) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$insertstatement);
                    
                    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query123)){
                                extract($r);
                  }
<!--GET-->
                    $co = (int)$co;
                    $name = $r['name'];
                    if($co == 1){
                    $result = array();
                    $result[] = array("name" => $name,"status" => 1);
               }
                    
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($result);
```

if username available / user registered .. the result name is empty.

> name :
>
> status : 1

Comment: and the question is?

Answer (score 0):

You write the query to get the count of the table having the uername and password given. Then how can you get the name using that query? Please study the things that you did before posting in the forums

Comment: Please study? im using MANUAL QUERY with this query = SELECT count(*) as co, name FROM `tbl_user` WHERE username='username' AND password='password' and i can GET the value name , but in this case i cant get with JSON .. do u understand with my problem?

Comment: @Edofx - $insertstatement = 'SELECT count(*) co FROM `tbl_user` WHERE username="'.$username.'" AND password="'.$password.'"';
May i know where is "name" in this query?

Answer (score 0):

1) Your not selecting name column . your only counting the row using count(*)

2) Mysql_* is derprecated try to use mysqli_* or PDO

3) Use prepared statement oR pdo when you dealing with user entered data to avoid sql injection

query :

```
SELECT count(*) as co, name FROM `tbl_user` WHERE username='username' AND password='password'
```

Update 1:

You already used extract to change it to variable . so directly access like this `$co = (int)$co;
       // $name = $r['name'];  //no need this line 
        if($co == 1){
           $result = array();
           $result[] = array("name" => $name,"status" => 1);
         }`

Comment: you already  used extract to change it as variable so your trying this $name = $r['name'];    use like this $name directly . @Edofx